# Passing in null for non-nullable int disappears in a Delta<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a typical endpoint for updating an entity

```
public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Individual> patch)
```

Individual has a non-nullable int property StatusId, which has the [Required] attribute. When "" is passed in, it properly throws the error:

**Request**

```
{ 
  "statusId": ""
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Request contains validation errors.",
        "details": [
            {
                "target": "patch",
                "message": "",
                "innerError": {
                    "message": "Cannot convert the literal '' to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'."
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However when I pass in null, it doesn't give a validation error, and the Delta object does not list it as a changed property.

**Request**

```
{ 
  "statusId": null
}
```

**Expected Response**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Request contains validation errors.",
        "details": [
            {
                "target": "patch",
                "message": "",
                "innerError": {
                    "message": "Cannot convert null to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'."
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

We want to be able to validate and return an error when they pass in null for a non-nullable field, not just silently ignore the error.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: It is marked required.